# Geometry getting ruined when doing cycles rendering?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, geometry

[image]The geometry of my model is being destroyed when I try to render it using the Cycles render engine.
The normals are not the issue. When I try to render it using Eevee or conduct a material preview, the geometry is perfect.
I've never had this problem.

Any solution will be helpful.
thank you[image: as shown in the picture]

Comment: pls provide your material setup or provide blend file. thx

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem you are experiencing is due to the Displacement node in your material setup.

Displacement does not work in Eevee, and so it is ignored.

When you render in Cycles, Blender is attempting to render the Displacement correctly, however there is not enough geometry (vertices) in your model for the Displacement to work correctly.

I would recommend simply deleting the Displacement node, which I don't believe you need as part of this material setup.

You could also have a look online for some tutorials on using Displacement in your materials - when it is appropriate and how to use. But in short, the Displacement node (and Displacement socket on the material output) is a means to *deform mesh data using material textures*. In other words, Blender will attempt to move vertices in a mesh according to the texture that is plugged into the Displacement node.

You will likely find that 99% of the materials you create do **not** require displacement.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that you have the color-space in your texture node for the normal map set to **non-color data**?

[image]

Any texture that is not directly influencing the color of your material should be set to non-color data (i.e. roughness/gloss, specularity, normal).You can get weird results otherwise.

If this is not the problem, could you please share a screenshot of your material node setup, or your .blend file?